# My php sessions keep being lost after login

Tags: php, session, xampp

I have read alot about the php security best practices on so, and I am trying hard to employ those on my xampp server.

I have an include that does all my security, ddos, session management, and in there is a function called sec_session_start. The code is below, but when i try to login, and then redirect back to my home page, all the session data is gone. On my login process page, before I do a redirect, it has all the correct session data.

After each header, i am doing "exit;". I have also tried writing session_write_close();

But that doesnt' seem to solve my problems.

Here is the function code.

```
function sec_session_start() {
$session_name = 'AnyName'; // Set a custom session name
$secure = false; // Set to true if using https.
$httponly = true; // This stops javascript being able to access the session id. 

ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); // Forces sessions to only use cookies. 
$cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); // Gets current cookies params.
session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly); 
session_name($session_name); // Sets the session name to the one set above.
session_start(); // Start the php session
session_regenerate_id(true); // regenerated the session, delete the old one.  
}
```

This function is called on every page.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is the code inside the include that get's called for every page. http://pastebin.com/e5r4Uvvu

Answer (score 5):

Drop the session_regenerate_id(true);

This is uncessary and won't overwrite previous cookies, but the "true" is the real problem as that cleans out the previous session details.

Comment: I dropped it, and when i redirect after successful login to home page, and i have a dump of sessions, it show's no values.

Comment: Well try dropping that entire function, except "session_start". The rest is overkill, expecially when trying to debug. Keep the sessionname if you HAVE to, but don;t if you've done it "just because"

Comment: Fair enough, just want this to be secure as possible.

Comment: Tried just session_start and it still doesn't save the session data after header redirect.

Comment: And session_start is before you modify $_SESSION?

Comment: correct, it is loaded on every page, one of the first things, before any php code is executed.

Comment: Will need to see more code, then. The "session_regenerate_id(true);" was definately a problem, but you must also have something else. Clear all cookies, and delete all functions reating to sessions except session_start() and $_SESSION[] assignments, and then build up from there.

Comment: I had a problem when clicking a page very fast, very often, I would get an error because username was not set on the session. Removing session_regenerate_id solved it. Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the cookie(s!) you're setting.  I had the same problem with the same function, and fixed it by explicitly stating my domain in session_set_cookie_params().  For some reason cookies for both www.example.com and example.com were being set.

The comments regarding session_regenerate_id(true) seem like a red herring, since that should copy over any existing session variables... and it also works.

```
function sec_session_start() {
    $domain = 'example.com'; // note $domain
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id'; // Set a custom session name
    $secure = true; // Set to true if using https.
    $httponly = true; // This stops javascript being able to access the session id. 
    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); // Forces sessions to only use cookies. 
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); // Gets current cookies params.
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $domain, $secure, $httponly); // note $domain
    session_name($session_name); // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_start(); // Start the php session
    session_regenerate_id(true); // regenerated the session, delete the old one.     
}
```