# process login not working in php

Tags: php

I'am a newbie in php and
I'am trying to create an login session in php. i have created a form and its action goes to process_login.php The codse in process_login.php is:

```
<?php
include_once 'sample/config.php';
include_once 'function.php';

sec_session_start(); 

if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['p'])) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['p']; 

if (login($username, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
    // Login success 
    header('Location: protected_page.php');
} else {
    // Login failed 
    header('Location: admin_login.php?error=1');
}
} else {

echo 'Invalid Request';
}
?>
```

this is the login page code:

```
<?php 
include('sample/config.php');
include_once 'function.php';

sec_session_start();

if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {
$logged = 'in';
} else {
$logged = 'out';
}
?>

<form action="process_login.php" method="post" name="login_form">
<label for="username">User name</label><br>
<input type="text" class="username" id="username" name="username" required>
<label for="password">Password</label><br>
<input type="password" class="password" id="password" name="password" required>
<button type="submit" class="submit" onClick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

after login this script has to redirect the page to protected_page.php or in the failed case it has to go to the admin_login.php.

but this is not working for now. its showing me process.php in the url after i clicked on submit.

Comment: Please provide more code, like the implementation of `sec_session_start()` and `login()`. Also make sure that the `$mysqli` argument you pass into `login()` exists and is valid.

Comment: show your login() code

Comment: may be sec_session_start(); function is not accessible here
see the Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152497/my-php-sessions-keep-being-lost-after-login

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using session_start() instead of sec_session_start().
If you want a secured session, you have to create the sec_session_start function using http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Comment: i'am trying same examole

Comment: I think you may have missed this function in Part 4.1. Be careful while using that as it uses cookies (and u need to ask your users permissions). I would suggest session_start() unless you really require otherwise

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean process.php? Is it the initial page where form is submitted? 
pls make sure in the form tag action="process_login.php" is included.

Comment: please add questions regrading post in comments.

Comment: yup its included in form tag action

Answer (score 0):

try `session_start()` and also your if check condition wrong for post values

```
session_start(); 

if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset( $_POST['p'])) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['p']; 

if (login($username, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
    // Login success 
    header('Location: protected_page.php');
} else {
    // Login failed 
    header('Location: admin_login.php?error=1');
}
} else {

echo 'Invalid Request';
}
?>
```

you have wrong code

```
sec_session_start(); 

if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['p'])) {
```

also what `login()` function works what is `$mysqli` please check this code is it fine or not

```
if (login($username, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
```

Comment: sec_session_start(); start session is secure way. i'am trying this from [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL)