# lost session in ajax call

Tags: php, ajax

I have an AJAX call in which user can order several times. I need get the id of the session, but the in doing so often call ajax the session is lost, causing the 'logout' automatically, how do I solve this?
`session_write_close(); // <-- // To allow parallel requests by the same user, while this script is still running.` but it did not work! =/

Thank you!

```
<?php
    require_once 'connect_db.php';
    require_once 'includes/functions.php';
    sec_session_start();
    $user_id = htmlentities($_SESSION['user_id']);
    session_write_close();
    if(isset($_POST['data_ajax']))
    {
        // do anything
        if (pg_send_query($con,"select * from users where id = $user_id"))
        {
         ...
        }
        $result[]=array("ajax_result"=>"0") //ok
    }
    else
    {
        $result[]=array("ajax_result"=>"1"); // not ok
    }
    echo json_encode($result); 
?>
```

I used this tutorial --> [wikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL)

Comment: Why do you need $user_id? You are not using it

Comment: @JulioSoares Oh, it's only a demo ... but I have the following code in there `if (pg_send_query($con,"select * from users where id = $user_id"))`

Comment: when I call the ajax / php I often lose my session.. =/

Comment: It seems to be a duplicate question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152497/my-php-sessions-keep-being-lost-after-login

Comment: @JulioSoares truth is identical!But it did not mention the source. however did not see answer... I will look closely at the comments

Comment: teh very first answer there points to a problem with the cookie and a solution

Comment: @JulioSoares well, when i click (without time out) several times in ajax request  I get the session expired. The code itself is ok!

Comment: @JulioSoares ok, I will comment the following line and try now `session_regenerate_id(true);`

Comment: for me it does not look ok, I never used a function like this and the session works 100% all the time.
I just call session_start and no matter how often I click it works as a charm.

Comment: @JulioSoares oooh it worked! session not expires more !! i only commented the `//session_regenerate_id(true);` and tested here !! thank you friend !! made my day!